# pyjks saves jks file which cannot be opened by keytool

Tags: python, keystore, pyjks

I want to use pyjks to load a keystore containing trusted certificates and I've been trying to add a trusted certificate, read from a file ('trust2.pub') into it.

```
import jks

ks = jks.KeyStore.load('trustore_file.jks', 'trustore_pass')

new_entry = jks.TrustedCertEntry.new("trust2", open('trust2.pub', 'rb').read())

# Since I have not found an explicit way to add a new TrustedCertEntry, 
# I thought this would work (add the 'new_entry' in the ks.entries dict).

ks.entries['trust2']=new_entry

# save the file with the new cert.

ks.save('trustore_file.jks', 'trustore_pass')
```

This actually saves the jks file with the new entry, which I can see if I try to reload the file with the given password. But when I try to open it with keytool in ubuntu, or KeyStore Explorer in Windows, I get the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length

So, maybe it's the way I add the new TrustedCertEntry in the jks file, but I could not know, since pyjks has no problem loading it.

If anybody can help on that, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was my mistake to import a **.pub** file. The correct file to import was a **.cer** file in **X.509 format**. So I'll leave this here if anyone else makes the same mistake.